# Keycloak: How to configure Apple Idp using OpenId connect provider type?

Tags: keycloak

I am using Keycloak v 21.0.1
I sent up Apple Idp provider on Keycloak usign oidc type.
Config:  Authorization Url: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize, Token Url: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token, Issuer: https://appleid.apple.com, ClientID: service ID with Sign in with Apple enabled, client secret: base64 part of private key.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Ugr.png)

The button appears and leads one to sign in with apple (good). But upon login, the user sees "Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider". The logs show:
2023-05-04 17:06:09,018 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (executor-thread-547) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: No access_token from server. error='invalid_client', error_description='null', error_uri='null'
at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.verifyAccessToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:574)
at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.getFederatedIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:384)
So it complains about "No access_token from server". Is there anything to be changed in the configuration?
Thank you.

I tried to use a custom provider https://github.com/ChathuminaVimukthi/Keycloak-with-Apple-Signin, but it does not work either. Shows Internal error in keycloak upon receival of redirect call.